# Unable to run Ruby code from text file (test.rb), but can run IRB and in the correct folder

Tags: ruby

Total Ruby Noob question... I've bought a book, read the websites, played in IRB, feel like I'm following instruction to the letter.

I am running OSX Mavericks so from the shell I can see ruby is installed...

```
Davids-iMac:~ asdf$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

I can run IRB and get sample code successfully run, etc.

I'm trying to save a text file and run the code from the console, like I'm all growed up with man-pants.  Behold my masterpiece:

```
puts “this is a test”
```

saved as a plain text file called "test.rb" in the folder: /Users/asdf/Ruby

I go to the directory in the console and see the file there...

```
Davids-iMac:~ asdf$ cd ruby
Davids-iMac:ruby asdf$ ls
test.rb
```

...I try to run the file using and get the following:

```
Davids-iMac:ruby asdf$ ruby test.rb
test.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `test”' for main:Object (NameError)
Davids-iMac:ruby asdf$
```

all i want is chunky bacon.  please help me get chunky bacon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your quotation marks from `”` to `"` and you should get your desired output.

Comment: Un.  Believable.  An auspicious start.  Thank you kind sir. For posterity this is accomplished in TextEdit by going to Edit -> Substitutions -> and turning off "Smart Quotes".  Which are aptly named because they can make you feel very, very dumb.

Comment: Don't worry.  We've all been there :-)